# finding hadoop-core-2.7.2.jar path

Tags: java, linux, bash, hadoop

I am new to hadoop and I am trying to run a code that use hadoop 1.2.1 version using hadoop 2.7.2 version. This is part of the code:

```
MR_HADOOPJAR=/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar
MR_MANIFEST=${rootPath}mp/src/manifest.txt
echo "Compiling mp source code.."
javac -classpath $MR_HADOOPJAR ${rootPath}mp/src/*.java
```

However, I can not find the hadoop-core-2.7.2.jar?? Any thoughts about the path of hadoop-core-2.7.2.jar??

Comment: Your question is not about running but about building. It would be better to use Gradle or Maven to build your application and then run it using `hadoop jar filename`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have hadoop-core jar in hadoop for this version, but we have hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.2.jar

Answer (score 0):

basically you can just

1. locate the 'hadoop-core-2.7.2.jar'
2. using the '-classpath' to include it into your compile process

Obviously the answer already lies in your code